# Show delete button if expire date id greater than current date in laravel Yajra table

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am using a Yajra table to retrieve data from a DB. At the moment I have a view button on the table to view data . On this I have to show a label to view records that are already expired.
This is my code
:

```
return DataTables::of($result)
      ->addIndexColumn()
      ->addColumn('action', function ($result) {
        return '<a data-id="' . $result->id . '" data-ref="' . $result->mbl_number . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary view_bl" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="View"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>';
      })
      ->addColumn('do-expire', function ($result) {
        if($result->do_expiry_date == "Expired"){
          return '<span class="label label-rejected" title="Expired">EXPIRED</span>';
        }else{

        }
     })
      ->rawColumns(['action', 'do-expire'])
      ->make(true);
```

In this I should show EXPIRED label only if `do_expiry_date > current_date`. I am not sure if I'm doing this the right way since I'm new to Yajra table.

If anyone can help me to achieve this much appreciated.

Comment: whats is the result above code?

Comment: Abed Putra it throws an error

Comment: show the error please..

Comment: Abed Putra, Thank you so much for your consideration. I figured a way to compare current date with expire date. And now it works without any error.